# Putting my Javascript arrays into a table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

With my program I am taking these values. Checking to see if they match and summarizing them. I have everything working except all my attempts to take the final data and put it into an table have failed.

I want to have the table be three rows and four columns. Each of the rows will be one of the finished arrays. Starting with the product name on the left and moving right per column

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var finished1 = ["Firex","Enrique",0,0];
var finished2 = ["Detector","Chris",0,0];
var finished3 = ["Hpvv","Diana",0,0];
var info = [];

info.push(["Firex", "Enrique", 6, 20000]);
info.push(["Detector", "Chris", 7, 35000]);
info.push(["Hpvv", "Diana", 12, 10000]);
info.push(["Firex", "Enrique", 4, 25000]);
info.push(["Detector", "Chris", 3, 15000]);
info.push(["Hpvv", "Diana", 3, 30000]);
info.push(["Firex", "Enrique", 8, 10000]);
info.push(["Detector", "Chris", 5, 20000]);
info.push(["Hpvv", "Diana", 6, 15000]);
info.push(["Firex", "Enrique", 5, 25000]);
info.push(["Detector", "Chris", 6, 35000]);
info.push(["Hpvv", "Diana", 7, 35000]);
info.push(["Firex", "Enrique", 3, 40000]);
info.push(["Detector", "Chris", 9, 10000]);
info.push(["Hpvv", "Diana", 5, 15000]);

info.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
  if(array[0][0] === array[index][0]) {
    finished1[2] += array[index][2];
    finished1[3] += array[index][3];
  }
  else if(info[1][0] === info[index][0]) {
    finished2[2] += array[index][2];
    finished2[3] += array[index][3];
  }
 else if(info[2][0] === info[index][0]) {
    finished3[2] += array[index][2];
    finished3[3] += array[index][3];
  }
});  

console.log(finished1);
console.log(finished2);
console.log(finished3);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what 'table' are you wanting to display this array in? Are you trying to just generate a table and push rows to it? Have you considered a 3rd party grid and just provide your data as a datasource? (eg kendoGrid from kendoUi)

Comment: well, try to 'hope' less and be more specific about what you are attempting to accomplish...it also helps to post your attempts as a jsfiddle or plunkr

Comment: i made an edit to make it more specific

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you create the table programmatically using DOM api, as @rlemon said.

```
//create the table DOM element
var table = document.createElement('table');

//create a row
var tr = document.createElement('tr');

//optional - adds headers to table
for(var x = 0; x < 4; x++){
   //create table header element
   var th = document.createElement('th');
   //set element text
   th.innerText = "header"+x;
   //append cell to row
   tr.appendChild(th);
}
//appends row to table
table.appendChild(tr);

//create another row
tr = document.createElement('tr');
for(var x = 0; x < 4; x++){
   //create cell
   var td = document.createElement('td');
   //set cell text
   td.innerText = finished1[x];
   tr.style.backgroundColor = "#AAA";//a little bit of color
   //append cell to row
   tr.appendChild(td);
}
table.appendChild(tr);

tr = document.createElement('tr');
for(var x = 0; x < 4; x++){
   var td = document.createElement('td');
   td.innerText = finished2[x];
   tr.appendChild(td);
}
table.appendChild(tr);

tr = document.createElement('tr');
for(var x = 0; x < 4; x++){
   var td = document.createElement('td'); 
   td.innerText = finished3[x];
   tr.style.backgroundColor = "#AAA";
   tr.appendChild(td);
}

table.appendChild(tr);

//append table to body
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @zipzit suggested you can use `document.write` to accomplish displaying your data on the page. You can write your `html` along with your data as a string in `JavaScript` like so:

```
var createTable = '<table><tr><td>' + finished1 + '</td></tr>' + '<tr><td>' + finished2 + '</td></tr>' + '<tr><td>' + finished3 + '</td></tr>' + '</table>'
```

And then utilize `document.write` to display that string on the page.

```
document.write(createTable);
```

Check out [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) docs on creating tables in `html` in order to add your desired table headers and other styling.

Comment: document.write has many caveats and HTML strings are generally considered a bad way to generate html in js. I would recommend using a more traditional way of generating HTML with the DOM api.